# Protege not inferring subclasses of a class as domain

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, reasoner

I am getting a confusion with Protege. May be it is a setting that I should configure somewhere that I am not doing.

Suppose I have an object property `hasFriend`. The domain and range of this object property is both `Person`. Now `Person` has two subclasses: `Man` and `Woman`.

The problem is when I launches the reasoner, HermiT (default reasoner in Protege), I was expecting to see that it adds `Man` and `Woman` as domain and ranges for `hasFriend` since they are subclasses of `Person`.

Is there a particular why I am not seeing these inferences ?

Comment: Why do you think so? The inference goes from bottom to top and not vice versa. If the domain is `Person` it can't infer a more specific type, that would be strange wouldn't it? And domain for example means, that a reason would infer the type of an individual using the property. In your example, `bob hasFriend kate` leads to bob being of type `Person`. Would be strange if the reasoner also returns `Woman` as type of `bob` , right?

Comment: Yes, you are right for the example, I get the point, thanks !!

Comment: @AKSW: I noticed that you often answer Semantic Web questions in the comments. Is there a reason for this? In case you’re not aware, [from the Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): "**When shouldn't I comment?** Answering a question […]". I think your answers would be valuable to have as actual answers.